# How to you abort/cancel a request using the prototype js library?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Using this code:

```
var pendingRequest =  new Ajax.Request(myUrl, {
               method: 'post',
               postBody: soapMsg,
               contentType: "text/xml",
               onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    doSomething(transport);
               },
               onFailure: function(t) {
                    OnAjaxFailure(t);
               },
               onException: function(req,exception) { 
                    OnAjaxException(req, exception);          
               } 

            });
```

How can I cancel the request and discard the data, or failing that, how could I identify the request (using a name/guid/whatever) inside my onSuccess method so that I can tell which request is completing?

I was thinking of doing an array.push(pendingRequest) to keep track of pending requests

I want to allow the user to interrupt their request, change the input values and resubmit.

Sometimes the original request ends after the new request and I'm replacing the "correct" data with the "old" data. (search results return 50,000 records on the first query and 5 in the second, for example)

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use XHR's [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29).

The XHR-object is stored in pendingRequest.transport, so using

```
pendingRequest.transport.abort()
```

would cancel the request.