# How to stop One Ajax Request if there is another Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

my whole site is almost Ajax based.

Page 1 = 
In my page 1 there are are 5 divs when first divs renders i put Ajax request for second div after the response i put Ajax request for third and same for others divs.
i have also other pages which is coming through Ajax.
lets say  user clicks on page 1 and just after first click user click on page 2 now **what i want to do is that i want to stop all the ajax requests that are on page 1 and process page 2 if user clicks on page 2 after page 1**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel XHR request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472086/cancel-xhr-request)

Comment: You'll need to keep a reference of previous Ajax requests in order to abort any of them.